# Ruby (Rails 4.0.2): (1 == true) => false?

Tags: ruby, sql-server, ruby-on-rails-4, boolean

My understanding is that in the Ruby programming language, only `nil` and `false` are considered `false`, and EVERYTHING else is considered true.

Thus, `1 == true` SHOULD return `true`.

I was working on a Rails 4.0.2 project using MS SQL Server (boolean field, tinyint(1)) and couldn't get the boolean working properly.  The value in the DB column was `1`.

Stumped, I started testing some things in the console.  Here's what I got in my Rails console:

- `1 == true # => false`
- `0 == true # => false`
- `"test" == true # => false`
- `"" == true # => false`

Why is everything registering as `false`?  I thought they were all supposed to be `true`?

I ended up having to do my boolean check via `<attribute>.to_i == 1` to get a valid true/false value.

Am I missing something in the Ruby language or was it updated in some version I wasn't aware of?  I'm using RVM, `ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883)` on a Mac machine.

**Updated: 2014-10-28 09:00**

After reading the excellent answers below, I understand where my thinking was wrong.

I think one of the problems is that most of the DB adapters I use (PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc...) converted boolean values in the DB for me.

For instance, in a lot of my code bases I have:

```
# User has an :admin boolean attribute
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def admin?
    admin == true
  end
end
```

And I suspect this works "fine" because the DB adapter takes care of converting the DB value to a proper boolean for me.

However, I'm currently work on a project where I'm required to use MS SQL Server, and I've run into many "gotchas" with the DB adapter, one of which is I don't believe it treats boolean fields the same as the other adapters do.

Thus, I always considered any TRUTHY value to be equal to `true`, which it is not.  I guess that's why `rspec` and others have moved to use `be_truthy` in their own syntax instead of purely `be_true`.

I'm just surprised it took me a few years before I ran into a problem like this!

Comment: `1==true` will be false, because they are different classes.

Comment: `nil` and `false` are *falsey*, everything else is *truthy*. There is a subtle difference between *false* and *falsey* and between *true* and *truthy*.

Comment: Short answer: Ruby is strictly typed, and (unlike JavaScript) will not perform type conversions for you when comparing values. `p :hi if 1` will work, so `1` is _truthy_, but that does not mean it is the same value as `true`.

Comment: Instead of `if attribute.to_i==1` just use `if attribute`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My understanding is that in the Ruby programming language, only nil and false are considered false, and EVERYTHING else is considered true

This is true.

However,

> "Thus, 1 == true SHOULD return true."

is false.

Explanation: in Ruby everything except false/nil is considered true. **However** when testing for equality, like `x == true` you're actually not testing "is this value considered true" but "is this value **equal** to true".

And of course `1` isn't equal to `true`, `1` is a number and `true` is a boolean value. You can read a very good blog post about equality in Ruby at "[Ruby Equality And Object Comparison](http://www.skorks.com/2009/09/ruby-equality-and-object-comparison/)".

If you really, really want to test it that way, you need to convert the expression like `1` to its boolean value, which you can do by double negating it. So `!!1 # => true`.

So, your examples will look like this:

```
!!1 == true # => true
!!0 == true # => true
!!"test" == true # => true
!!"" == true # => true
```

However I believe it isn't necessary in most cases.

When working with MSSQL you should let Active Record do all the conversions for you. Declare the field in a migration, with type boolean, and when you do your `where` search in the database, do it like this:

```
Model.where(['attribute = ?', true])
Model.where(:attribute=> true)
```

This way ActiveRecord will do all the work related to converting the type to a database compatible one for you.

Comment: Actually, `true` is a [TrueClass](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/TrueClass.html): `true.class
# => TrueClass < Object`

Comment: It's true - but I believe it doesn't actually make any difference here ;)

Answer (score 1):

In terms of logical predicates every object besides `nil` and `false` are **TRUTHY**. What basically means that statement corresponding our predicate (condition) will be executed.

While `nil` and `false` are **FALSEY** predicate.

In practice it means:

```
if predicate
  statement_a
else
  statement_b
end
```

Whatever is not a predicate, except `nil` and `false` `statement_a` will be executed. Otherwise `statement_b` will get the jack pot.

Answer (score 0):

First off, your assumption that everything in Ruby that isn't false or nil is considered true, is true.

Let's take each of your four examples:

```
1 == true # => false
```

When evaluating this expression, Ruby takes the class of the first argument, looks for the operator method and evaluates. So, for Fixnums, it evaluates whether or not 1 is equal to another Numeric number. [Fixnum#== docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Fixnum.html#method-i-3D-3D) that is equivalent to 1.

```
0 == true # => false
```

Same as above.

```
"test" == true # => false
```

This is doing an equality test through the String class. As stated in the [String#== docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-3D-3D), the class is tested on the right side and if it isn't a string, but responsed to `to_str` (true does), then the Object#=== method is used and the evaluation asks if the two are the same object, which is not the case here.

```
"" == true # => false
```

This is the same as above.

Esse's answer is correct in showing that all objects other than false and nil are true.

```
!!false # => false
!!nil # => false
```

Answer (score 0):

The `==` is a method just like any other method in Ruby that a class uses to decide whether the passed parameter (the parameter on the right side) is equal to its object or not, just like you can define your own `==` method for your classes. In fact you could even modify the way `==` methods works for any Ruby basic object such as `Fixnum` if you wish.

So when you say `1 == true` what you are actually saying is `1.==(true)` in which case the class `Fixnum` doesn't like to consider the passed parameter `true` to be equal to its object `1`.

Now when you say everything in Ruby except `nil` and `false` are considered true, the correct statement is that in Ruby only `false` and `nil` are **falsey** and everything else is **truthy**. So when Ruby has to decide whether a value or object **count as** or **evaluates** as true (such as in an if statement: `if ('test')`), it determines whether it is **truthy** or **falsey**, but not whether  `(object).==(true)` returns true or false